# Problem with Java Scanner sc.nextLine();

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

sry about my english :)
Im new to Java programming and i have a problem with Scanner. I need to read an Int, show some stuff and then read a string so i use **sc.nextInt();** show my stuff **showMenu();** and then try to read a string **palabra=sc.nextLine();**

Some one told me i need to use a sc.nextLine(); after sc.nextInt(); but i dont understand why do you have to do it :(

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int respuesta = 1;

    showMenu();
    respuesta = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //Why is this line necessary for second scan to work?

    switch (respuesta){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("=== Palindromo ===");
            String palabra = sc.nextLine();
            if (esPalindromo(palabra) == true)
                System.out.println("Es Palindromo");
            else
                System.out.println("No es Palindromo");
        break;
    }


}
```

Ty so much for your time and Help :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nextInt()` only reads in until it's found the int and then stops.

You have to do `nextLine()` because the input stream still has a newline character and possibly other non-int data on the line. Calling `nextLine()` reads in whatever data is left, including the enter the user pressed between entering an int and entering a String.

Comment: The first time I ran into this issue it stumped me too, but once you know why it makes sense!

Comment: is nice to know im not the only one :D

Answer (score 4):

When you input a value (whether `String`, `int`, `double`, etc...) and hit 'enter,' a new-line character (aka `'\n'`) will be appended to the end of your input. So, if you're entering an int, `sc.nextInt()` will only read the integer entered and leave the `'\n'` behind in the buffer. So, the way to fix this is to add a `sc.nextLine()` that will read the leftover and throw it away. This is why you need to have that one line of code in your program.